# React, having trouble setting component state inside the promise

Tags: ajax, reactjs, promise

I'm having trouble setting component's state inside the promise using previous state.
code here - https://gist.github.com/red4211/1b8ae503fc76b7a3771d45eca0b81a19

Commented out part is wrong, but hopefully gives you the idea of what i'm trying to do here.

Please help me out, i'm stuck.

Thanks for your help guys, everything is working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's binding issue, to solve that use `arrow function`:

```
this.props.list.map((current) => {
    api.getStreamInfo("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+current)
    .then((response) => {
         console.log(response.data);
         let streamObj = this.state.streamObj.slice();
         streamObj.push(response.data);
         this.setState({ streamObj })
    });
})
```

or You can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) also:

```
this.props.list.map((current) => {
    api.getStreamInfo("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+current)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);         
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ streamObj: [...prevState.streamObj, response.data] }))
    });
})
```

**array.push** will not return the updated `array`, it will return the pushed item only, so first copy the `array` in a separate variable do the changes then use `setState` to update the value.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2];

let b = [...a, 3];

console.log('a:', a);
console.log('b:', b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `promise` function and then `update` state. Make use of `concat` since it returns a new array

Do it like

```
this.props.list.map(function(current){
     api.getStreamInfo("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+current)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState(function(prevState, props){
          streamObj: prevState.streamObj.concat(response.data);
        })
      }.bind(this));
    })
```

or

```
 this.props.list.map(function(current){
     api.getStreamInfo("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/"+current)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        var streamObj = [...this.state.streamObj];
        streamObj.push(response.data)
        this.setState({streamObj})
      }.bind(this));
    })
```